# I can't seem to work a way for my recommend program to track "Invalid Answers"

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, statements

Here is the code:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Question #1:");

    System.out.println("What is your budget for purchasing the laptop?");

    System.out.println("A. >$500.00");
    System.out.println("B. $500.00 - $700.00");
    System.out.println("C. $700.00 - $1000.00");
    System.out.println("D. <$1000.00");
    questionArray [0] = myScanner.nextLine();
    if (!questionArray [0].equals ("A") || !questionArray [0].equals ("B") || !questionArray [0].equals ("C") || !questionArray [0].equals ("D")) {
      System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
    }
} while (!questionArray [0].equals ("A") || !questionArray [0].equals ("B") || !questionArray [0].equals ("C") || !!questionArray [0].equals ("D"));
```

Basically, even when I write a valid response (eg. "A") it still counts it as an invalid answer, and restarts the question.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the condition gets complex, it is a good idea to try and simplify the complexity by using variables to make code cleaner and easier to understand. For example:

```
    boolean validCondition = false;

    do {
        System.out.println("Question #1:");
        System.out.println("What is your budget for purchasing the laptop?");

        System.out.println("A. >$500.00");
        System.out.println("B. $500.00 - $700.00");
        System.out.println("C. $700.00 - $1000.00");
        System.out.println("D. <$1000.00");

        questionArray[0] = myScanner.nextLine();

        validCondition = questionArray[0].equals("A") || questionArray[0].equals("B") || questionArray[0].equals("C")
                || questionArray[0].equals("D");

        if (!validCondition) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
        }
    } while (!validCondition);
```

Comment: Wow that simplified it a lot, thanks so much for the help! I never really think of using boolean operators, but not I can see where I could simplify much more in my code! :)

Answer (score 1):

JB's answer notwithstanding, it is often easier to express the logic more readably like this:

```
private static final List<String> VALID_ANSWERS = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
```

then:

```
do {
    // ...
    questionArray[0] = myScanner.nextLine();
    if (!VALID_ANSWERS.contains(questionArray[0])) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
    }
} while (!VALID_ANSWERS.contains(questionArray[0]))
```

Comment: Ummm, I haven't learned about that yet in Com Sci (Grade 11), and I think I'l have a hard time explaining to the teacher what that means. But thanks for the help anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

if the answer is "A", then `questionArray[0].equals("B")` is false, so `!questionArray[0].equals("B")` is true, so the whole `or` expression is true, so the answer is invalid.

Replace `||` by `&&`.

Or use

```
if (!(questionArray[0].equals("A") || questionArray[0].equals("B") || questionArray[0].equals("C") || questionArray[0].equals("D")))
```

Or even better, use

```
private static final Set<String> VALID_ANSWERS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
```

and

```
if (!VALID_ANSWERS.contains(questionArray[0]))
```

Comment: Interesting, now whenever I enter a valid answer it repeats the question, but doesn't output the message of being invalid. Do you only replace the if statements with && ?